# Keyframe Animation failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation

I want to add shaking effect to a UIView,but I failed.here is my code

```
    CGRect rectL=CGRectMake(473, 473, 88, 88);
    CGRect rectR=CGRectMake(493, 473, 88, 88);
    NSValue *valueL = [NSValue value: &rectL
                         withObjCType:@encode(CGRect)];
    NSValue *valueR = [NSValue value: &rectR
                        withObjCType:@encode(CGRect)];
    NSArray *firstArray=@[valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        CAKeyframeAnimation * theAnimation;

        // Create the animation object, specifying the position property as the key path.
        theAnimation=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
        theAnimation.values=firstArray;
        theAnimation.duration=5.0;
        theAnimation.calculationMode= kCAAnimationLinear;
        // Add the animation to the layer.
        [self.boView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"frame"];//boView is an outlet of UIView
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];
```

When I run the code,the view is still,no shaking.Why?

**UPDATE**

I have to use keyframe animation because after the view shakes,it needs to move to another place and then shakes and then stops.  Here is my edited code,but it still not works.Why?

```
    CGRect rectL=CGRectMake(463, 473, 88, 88);
    CGRect rectR=CGRectMake(503, 473, 88, 88);
    NSValue *valueL = [NSValue value: &rectL
                         withObjCType:@encode(CGRect)];
    NSValue *valueR = [NSValue value: &rectR
                        withObjCType:@encode(CGRect)];
    NSArray *firstArray=@[valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR];



    CAKeyframeAnimation * theAnimation;

    // Create the animation object, specifying the position property as the key path.
    theAnimation=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
    theAnimation.values=firstArray;
    theAnimation.duration=5.0;
    theAnimation.calculationMode= kCAAnimationLinear;
    // Add the animation to the layer.
    [self.boView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"frame"];
```

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up two completely separate ways of animating.

Comment: Probably because of the weird way you are doing it (CAAnimation inside a UIView animation block).  You should just make one CAAnimation, and then you can set autoreverse and repeatCount.

Comment: 1) Any reason for not using `[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rectR]`?
2) Any reason for not animating the `position` since you don't change the size?
Also, mixing UIView animations and Core Animation like that =  the horrors!

Comment: @Fogmeister According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW3  "If you want to use Core Animation classes to initiate animations, you must issue all of your Core Animation calls from inside a view-based animation block. The UIView class disables layer animations by default but reenables them inside animation blocks. So any changes you make outside of an animation block are not animated"

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 Yes, and that quote boils down to "*implicit* animations are off by default for views but they are on if you do them inside an animation block" What you are doing is an *explicit* animation inside of a block. Trust me, it will animate just fine without the animation block. In facts it's much cleaner.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Thank you,I have edited the code,but it still not works.Can you help me?

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 I though I just did (my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The `frame` property is not directly animatable.

---

From [the documentation of the frame property on CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/frame):

> **Note:** The `frame` property is not directly animatable. Instead you should animate the appropriate combination of the `bounds`, `anchorPoint` and `position` properties to achieve the desired result.

In your example you are only changing the position anyway so even if you could animate the frame it would be better to animate the position.

### Other remarks

#### NSValue

Instead of `[NSValue value:&rect withObjCType:@encode(CGRect)]` I would prefer the specialised  `[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]` (or `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]` in this case)

#### Animation blocks

As already said in the comments: you should only combine Core Animation and animation blocks when you are doing implicit animations (since they are disables for views otherwise). What you are doing is an *explicit* animation so there is no need to do so.

#### The "key" in `addAnimation:forKey:`

It is a common misconception that the key you pass when adding animation is the property that you are changing. That is not the case. The `keyPath` is already configured on the animation.

That key is used for you to be able to ask the layer for animations that have been added to it using `animationForKey:` If you plan on asking the layer for it I suggest you give it a more descriptive string. Otherwise you can just pass `nil`.

---

## The modified code

I've modified your code below according to these remarks

```
CGPoint leftPoint  = CGPointMake(473, 473);
CGPoint rightPoint = CGPointMake(493, 473);

NSValue *leftValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:leftPoint];
NSValue *rightValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:rightPoint];
NSArray *firstArray = @[leftValue, rightValue,
                        leftValue, rightValue,
                        leftValue, rightValue,
                        leftValue, rightValue];

CAKeyframeAnimation * theAnimation;

// Create the animation object, specifying the position property as the key path.
theAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
theAnimation.values = firstArray;
theAnimation.duration = 5.0;
theAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
// Add the animation to the layer.
[self.boView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation 
                         forKey:@"moveBackAndForth"]; //boView is an outlet of UIView
```

Comment: Amazing!It works well.And thank you very much for you well explaining.

Comment: But I don't understand "The keyPath is already configured on the animation".Where can I get the list of key?And is "moveBackAndForth" a special key or something at will?

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 When you create an animation using `animationWithKeyPath:` you are setting the `keyPath` property on the animation. You can get a list of animation keys for a layer by calling  `animationKeys` on the layer. The string "moveBackAndForth" is just a string I made up. You can use any string you want. I simply tried to describe what the animation does.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
CABasicAnimation *theRotateAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
[theRotateAnimation setDuration:0.2f];
theRotateAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[theRotateAnimation setRepeatCount:CGFLOAT_MAX];
[theRotateAnimation setAutoreverses:YES];
[theRotateAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(- 2 * (M_PI / 180))]];
[theRotateAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2 * (M_PI / 180))]];
[self.boView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
[self.boView.layer addAnimation:theRotateAnimation forKey:@"RotateAnimation"];
```

This will definitely shake your view.

Comment: Thank you,but I have to use Keyframe Animation because I need something more than shaking.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

try this,the simple code for shake view animation

```
CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [shake setDuration:0.2];
    [shake setRepeatCount:4];
    [shake setAutoreverses:YES];
    [shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                         CGPointMake(View.center.x - 5,View.center.y)]];
    [shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                       CGPointMake(View.center.x + 5, View.center.y)]];
    [View.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: Thank you,but I have to use Keyframe Animation because I need something more than shaking.Can you help me?